# searching date range shows strange results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

When I query my dataset like this:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {
        "range" : {
            "time_written" : {
                "gte": "2009-01-01",
                "lte": "2011-01-01",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

I find results with the time_written 2010-10-12

But with this query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {
        "range" : {
                "time_written" : {
                    "gte": "2010-01-01",
                    "lte": "2011-01-01",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
        }
    }
}
'
```

The results with time_written 2010-10-12 are not being found. Any idea why that is happening?

**update**

mapping:

```
{
    "textobject-index":{
        "mappings":{
            "doc":{
                "properties":{
                    "main_text":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fielddata":true
                    },
                    "time_written":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fielddata":true
                    },
                    "translated_text":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fielddata":true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example of result:

```
{
    "took":1,
    "timed_out":false,
    "_shards":{
        "total":5,
        "successful":5,
        "skipped":0,
        "failed":0},
    "hits":{
        "total":1,
        "max_score":1.0,
        "hits":[{
            "_index":"textobject-index",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"10",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
                "main_text":"some long text",
                "time_written":"2010-10-12"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query is only returning 10 results (by default), maybe the record is there, but just not visible. How many total documents do you see in the response?

Comment: Nice idea, but the total number of results is 0

Comment: Can you how the document that is supposed to be returned? And your mapping as well?

Comment: yes I have now updated the question with that info

Comment: That's what I thought, the `time_written` field is not a `date` field but a `text` field, hence the range filtering is not working like you expect. You need to change the type of `time_written` and reindex your data. Then your query will work.

Comment: yes that is correct, the strange thing is that in my python code using elasticsearch-dsl the field is defined as a Date() and the mapping is the same even after deleting the index and bulk indexing again

Comment: Then you need to show the relevant part of your code.

Comment: fixed the rest after you spotted the text instead of date in mapping, thanks